# Can't redirect to a new page using js

Tags: jquery, redirect

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server/blob/master/form-submission-handler.js) to have contact form submissions sent to a google spreadsheet. Between lines 89-99 I added the following to redirect to a thank-you page instead of displaying a thank-you div:

```
if (!validEmail(data.email)) {   // if email is not valid show error
    document.getElementById('email-invalid').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
} else {
    var url = event.target.action;  //
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    // xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log( xhr.status, xhr.statusText )
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        //document.getElementById('gform').style.display = 'none'; // hide form
        // document.getElementById('thankyou_message').style.display = 'block'; 
        window.location.href = "mensaje-enviado.html";
        return;
    };
```

Here's a [*working* link](http://bellotaestudio.com/reside/los-olmos/bali.html), can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So... I looked at it, you have an error showing up: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at HTMLDocument.loaded (form-submission-handler.js:100)`. This probably has something to do with it.

Comment: Change `<form class="gform"` to `<form id="gform"`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Indeed, per mplungjan's comment, my mistake was using class instead of id. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a anchor tag element with target set to "_blank" in your HTML with display none

```
<a id="thankYouLinkId" href="thankYouLinkUrl" target="_blank" style="display: none;">Test Link</a>
```

Now use javascript code to open the thankYouLinkUrl in new tab:

```
document.getElementById("thankYouLinkId").click();
```